# How to obtain specific data based on a condition in a list in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of animals that were radio-tracked for a year. However, the radio-tracking events were uneven and sometimes animals were tracked 3 times a week, and sometimes only once a month.

I have provided a dummy dataset of relevant columns.

In this picture, I have the IDs of 3 different animals. If you take animal ID 0-10, you can see that under the value column there is a 57. This means there is a gap of 57 days between consecutive tracking days.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
    date = c("2015-05-01","2015-05-04","2015-05-05","2015-07-01","2015-07-02","2015-07-05","2015-07-06",
     "2015-05-01","2015-05-04","2015-05-05","2015-05-27","2015-05-28","2015-06-05","2015-06-06",
     "2015-05-01","2015-05-02","2015-05-03","2015-05-04","2015-05-05","2015-05-06","2015-05-07")

    ID = c("0-10","0-10","0-10","0-10","0-10","0-10","0-10",
   "0-2","0-2","0-2","0-2","0-2","0-2","0-2",
   "0-8","0-8","0-8","0-8","0-8","0-8","0-8")


    data2015v2 = data.frame(date,ID)
    data2015v2$date = as.Date(data2015v2$date)

    delta.days.2015 = with(data2015v2, tapply(date, ID, FUN = function (x) as.integer(diff(x))))
```

I want to know which animals have gaps longer than 14 days, without having to go over each list one by one. I think I need to use a loop, but I don't know how to set up one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share a reproducible sample of the data set rather than an image. Would it be possible to share a subset of `data2015v2` as well?

Comment: I have edited the post to add a very small dummy dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you could `group_by` animal ID, and `summarize` the data to include just the maximum gap (in days):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


data2015v2 %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(max_gap = max(date - lag(date), na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   ID    max_gap
#>   <chr> <drtn> 
#> 1 0-10  57 days
#> 2 0-2   22 days
#> 3 0-8    1 days
```

To have the resulting data frame only include IDs where there was a gap in monitoring that exceeded 14 days, you could `filter` on the max_gap column:

```
data2015v2 %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(max_gap = max(date - lag(date), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(max_gap > 14)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   ID    max_gap
#>   <chr> <drtn> 
#> 1 0-10  57 days
#> 2 0-2   22 days
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>